# Apache conf get value from remotehost and set in header

Tags: apache, .htaccess, httpd.conf

I have a requirement, where I have to extract value from Remote host name and set it in header for example if the URL is like this -
http://data1-data2.server.com/someuri

From the above example, data1 and data2 needs to be extracted and set in a header i.e. X-HEADER1=data1 & X-HEADER2=data2.

I initially tried RewriteRule but found, that it is only applicable for the URI and not servername

```
RewriteRule (?<=//)(.*)(?=-) - [E=INFO_REQUEST_CONTEXT_1:$1,NE]
RewriteRule (?<=-)(.*?)(?=[.]) - [E=INFO_REQUEST_CONTEXT_2:$1,NE]
RequestHeader set X-HEADER1 "%{INFO_REQUEST_CONTEXT_1}e"
RequestHeader set X-HEADER2 "%{INFO_REQUEST_CONTEXT_2}e"
```

What would be the right configuration to use?

Answer (score 1):

Following configuration works,

```
# Extract data1 from URL and set the header
SetEnvIf Host "(.*)(?=-)" var1=$1   
RequestHeader set X-HEADER1 %{var1}e env=var1
# Extract data2 from URL and set the header 
SetEnvIf Host "(?<=-)(.*?)(?=[.])" var2=$1  
RequestHeader set X-HEADER2 %{var2}e env=var2
```

Answer (score 0):

Enable `mod_rewrite` and `mod_headers` through `httpd.conf` (if not already enabled) and then put this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

# capture REMOTE_HOST components in env variables
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_HOST} ^([^-]+)\.([^.]+)\.
RewriteRule ^ - [E=INFO_REQUEST_CONTEXT_1:%1,E=INFO_REQUEST_CONTEXT_2:%2,L]

## set custom response headers to be used in server side scripts
RequestHeader set X-HEADER1 "%{INFO_REQUEST_CONTEXT_1}e"
RequestHeader set X-HEADER2 "%{INFO_REQUEST_CONTEXT_2}e"

## set custom response headers    
Header always set X-HEADER1 "%{INFO_REQUEST_CONTEXT_1}e"
Header always set X-HEADER2 "%{INFO_REQUEST_CONTEXT_2}e"
```

[**mod_headers reference**](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_headers.html#requestheader)

Comment: Isn't this going to set the variables in the response header rather than request header? Maybe this is what the question was about though. :-)

Comment: How can you set/modify the request headers after it has already landed in web server?

Comment: Not sure you can, but I guess `RequestHeader` do something with the request header. I was just unsure if that was what the question was all about.

Comment: @Qben: You are right, I did more reading and found that request headers can be set to used in server side scripts. Please check the updated answer.

Comment: Anubhava, I tried out the conf but %{REMOTE_HOST} is returning back IP address. The request flow is somthing like this - Browser --> BIG IP --> OHS(apache) --> Weblogic. In the application deployed in weblogic,I can see the URL used by the client in the browser.  
Also, on what basis does the split happen? i.e. this line -`RewriteRule ^ - [E=INFO_REQUEST_CONTEXT_1:%1,E=INFO_REQUEST_CONTEXT_2:%2,L]`

Comment: REMOTE_HOST is the identification of the client and I am not surprised if that is just IP address. What is not clear to me is why do you want to make this rule based on client. Should that not be based on HOST_NAME variable which denotes Domain name part in the URL.